# Datetime: Check if date is in 1 week

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

What I am trying to do is see if `date` is in 1 week from `currdate`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import yagmail

year = datetime.now().year
month = datetime.now().month
day = datetime.now().day

currdate = '{}-{}-{}'.format(year, month, day)
currdate = datetime.strptime(currdate, '%Y-%m-%d')

date = '2018-04-01'

days = currdate - timedelta(int(date[-2:]))
days = str(days)
print(days)

if days[8:11] == '07':
    yag = yagmail.SMTP("#########@gmail.com", "######")
    content = ['One Of Your Homework\'s Is Due In 1 Week!']
    yag.send('##########@gmail.com', 'Homework Due Soon!', content)
else:
    print('It Isn\'t')
```

But it prints:

```
2018-04-07 00:00:00

It Isnt't
```

And I'm not sure why. Because `days[8:11]` is `07`.

Comment: `timedelta(int(date[-2:]))` <- Is this for real? You throw away the year and the month and try to find out if the date is within one week just based on the day? What on earth is going on in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `07`. It's `07` (note the trailing space).

The following change will work:

```
if int(days[8:11]) == 7:
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a function that you pass the date as a string. Something like this:

```
import datetime

def check_if_less_than_seven_days(x):
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d") # Add .date() if hour doesn't matter
    now = datetime.datetime.now()                 # Add .date() if hour doesn't matter
    return (d - now).days < 7

if check_if_less_than_seven_days("2018-04-18"):
    print('Do something')  # This will not print

if check_if_less_than_seven_days("2018-04-14"): 
    print('Do something')  # This will print
```

Will print:

```
'Do something'
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your first line when you initiate datetime.now() three times is just for testing purposes but dont do this as it could end up over different days (if you run this exactly at the milliseconds around midnight..) this will work better in that regard.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
day = now.day
```

Anyway, read up on datetime timedelta. Just make you logic around that.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

```
import datetime
test_date_string = "2018-04-10"
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(test_date_string, "%Y-%m-%d")
now = datetime.datetime.now()

delta = d - now
elif delta.days < 7:
    print("You have less then 7 days to go")
```

Answer (score 0):

For days[8:11] you get the following output

```
>>> days[8:11] 
'08 '
```

So you should use days[8:10]=='07' in case you want to use the same method,as it wont have extra space at the end.

```
>>> days[8:10] 
'08'
```

so you should use
    if days[8:10] == '07':